# VideoJS not working on mobile

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, mobile, video.js

I am using VideoJS to play videos served up from a fileserver.  The files are in mp4 format, and work fine (using Flash fallback) on any desktop browser.  However they do not work at all on mobile devices.  For reference, feel free to check out:

`http://74.203.203.93/content/aacfc5e7-fbeb-4785-ad04-023856a54a3d`

I've tried to work the code around every which way I can think of to get it to work, but apparently I'm missing something somewhere.  Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

More information:

Constants:

- Video is in mp4 format (H.264 according to MediaInfo showing video codec being AVC).
- Multiple formats are not possible (there will be no more than 1 (one) "source" tag).
- Video file is hosted in a file server without a filename.  Browser gets the location, and gets a source type tag.
- Server is IIS.
- Server supports byte-range requests.

Attempts so far:

- Per http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/539-playing-mp4-on-android-using-videojs

  - Removed "type='video/mp4'" from tag.
  - Checked MIME types on server, video/mp4 is showing.
- Per https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md

  - Added javascript to call play() on ready.
- Extension of above: tried javascript to call play() on click.
- Tried adding '.mp4' to the end of the guid in the src location.
- Swapped position of "type" and "src" elements of "source" tag.
- I have changed the https:// in the source to http:// per several locations saying mobile doesn't do https well.
- I changed the relative url in the src to an absolute url.

I will update with more information as I continue...

Comment: in your code the source-video gives me a 404, are you shure it's correct?

Comment: Yeah I got that too.  Someone added a new site and assigned it to the same IP address as what I'm working on.  It'll be available again in a minute.

Comment: The mixup has been resolved and it is accessible.

Comment: DNS lookup fails for dev.contentserver.zywave.com, so your video file is not reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the great media wars flash has been eliminated from androids, thats why the webm file is a key component in videojs.The mp4 file must be converted into a webm file and both sources used. You can just upload the webm vid to fileserver as well and link both sources in the player. The filenames in the link to the server must end in .mp4 and .webm to be recognized.

2 must reads -
http://www.zdnet.com/androids-flash-player-is-dead-live-with-it-7000002668/

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3417930/how-get-flash-in-android-jelly-bean/

The quickest way to convert a mp4 to webm without software is to upload it to youtube, once the video is there copy the link and go to keepvid.com, then download the webm. Remember the highest quality webm file is not always optimal do to the size of mobile devices and slow internet connections planetwide. The video quality toggle on videojs is on the way though.

Comment: I accepted this answer, although the problem lies with ASP.Net.  I ran into the same issue with VideoJS, FlowPlayer, and JW Player.  This answer just has relevant information that other people who can upload their videos to youtube might use.  Unfortunately I do not have that liberty.