# Videojs does not play on Samsung devices (Android 4.0, 4.2)

Tags: android, video, samsung-mobile

We included the Player in our Website (not online yet) and it does´t play in all Samsung devices. Two run with Jelly Bean the other with Ice Cream Sandwich. [Also the video on videojs.com´s homepage does´t play (Samsung Galaxy S3, S3 Mini, Galaxy Tab 2)]. You can see the Player but it´s not able to play.  On the website I tried both: Embedding only mp4 and embedding all formats. With an OGV-File it works at least in Firefox. Flash is not installed because it should run with HTML5.

It seems as if the Browser (Internet, Chrome, Dolphin, Opera) can read the HTML5 because the Player is shown but they have a problem to load the mp4-File.

- I read that one problem could be that some encoder put the
  index-information of an mp4-file at the and of the file so that it
  can make trouble to stream it. I tested our files with
  QTIndexSwapper. The index is right so that is not the problem.
- And I read many articles about how to install flash or different
  players. But I would like to let it play without any additional
  installations so everybody can see it immediately.
- I read this article
  [VideoJS not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075436/videojs-not-working-on-mobile).
  My files all have the right endings.

The site is still on a development server with htaccess. Can that be
   the problem?

Is there any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don´t like the htaccess password protection. But also without it the videos didn´t play everywhere. We had to write

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

in our .htaccess.